# How to find elements in Selenium Web Driver by.xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I had this HTML output (Firebug):

```
<a class="tab-toolbar-button tab-widget tab-disabled" title = "Revert All">
<span clas = "tab-toolbar-button-icon tab-icon-revert"></span>
</a>
```

But after upgrading server and new interface I have this:

```
<div class="tabToolbarButton tab-widget disabled">
  <span class="tabToolbarButtonImg tab-icon-revert"></span>
  <span class="tabToolbarButtonText">Revert</span>
</div>
```

My Java code was:

```
private static void doResetFilter() throws Exception {
    waitForLoadingSpinner();
element =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'tab-toolbar-button')][@title='Revert All']")));

boolean isEnabled = element.getAttribute("class").contains("tab-enabled");

if (isEnabled) {
        log("reset filter");
        element.click();
    }
    else {
        log("filter reset not needed");
    }
}
```

Now I need to modify my Java code to be compatible with new version. Cause I am new with Selenium and Java (I inherited this code), how can I change part with text?

I have tried like this but still there is no result. Can anyone help?

```
private static void doResetFilter() throws Exception {
        waitForLoadingSpinner();

        element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class=’Revert’]")));


        boolean isEnabled = element.getAttribute("class").contains("enabled");

        if (isEnabled) {
            log("reset filter");
            element.click();
        }
        else {
            log("filter reset not needed");
        }

    }
```

Thanks upfront!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate the `div` element with a desired `@class` having a `span` child with a desired text:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'tabToolbarButton') and span = 'Revert']
```

Comment: I have tried and seems like it is doing something, I will apply this logic on second part of the code also to check behavior. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if u want the element which text is "Revert" use the below code:

```
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.tabToolbarButton.tab-widget.disabled>span.tabToolbarButtonText")));
```

one more thing, in your new html, there is no class in span that contains

```
enabled
```

one div contains disabled.

So let me know this helps or not or you need other thing.

Comment: I have tried, but still not entering in next tab. But thank you on suggestion, cause I haven't thought that I can do it also via cssSelector :)